# oracle sql developer connection

Tags: java, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I tried to install oracle sql developer in windows 7 32 bit for this first i install jdk 8 and then i install this file `sqldeveloper-4.1.3.20.78-no-jre` from oracle website .. then when i run sqldeveloper application it shows this

check image
[image: image 1]

then this shows create new connection now when i create connection it shows error 
check image

[image: image 2]

how to solve this error?

Comment: make sure DB is installed, up, running and you can connect to it. Can you connect via sqlplus?

Comment: If you go to the command prompt and run `sqlplus HR/HR` what happens? If it fails can you do `sqlplus / as sysdba` then at the sql prompt run `ALTER USER HR IDENTIFIED BY "HR" ACCOUNT UNLOCK;` then `EXIT`. Can you then run `sqlplus HR/HR`? If that works can you exit and run `sqlplus HR/HR@XE` does that connect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart the suggestions of @Nikita and @thatjeffsmith, I highly suspect the matter is that you are using the pre-existing user `hr` that you didn't create by yourself but that was created during installing your Oracle Express instance.

This user is **by default locked**. It must be unlocked by an administrator (for example `SYSTEM` user).

After unlocking hr user, don't forget to grant to it `CONNECT` and `RESOURCE` roles.
Find more details on [this page.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B25329_01/doc/admin.102/b25610/toc.htm)

Comment: The error is in the initial connection to the database. If the connection completed to the database and the HR account was locked, there would be a different error.

Answer (score 3):

You need to install Oracle Express Edition (XE) and set it up to run on your computer, on port 1521 - for your connection to work.

SQL Developer is just a client - there's no database there, unless you've put it there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a running database to use with SQL Developer. If you haven't installed it yet follow the [official documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/index.htm). If you do have the database but can't connect to it, make sure that

- The [listener](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/win.111/b32010/ap_net.htm) is up and running on the machine you're trying to connect to (in your case it's `localhost`)
- You've provided the correct port number and SID